# php grab contents of a page before rendering using SimpleHTMLDOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

OK, the title is vague but i just dont know how to word this.

what I want to do is parse the entire page before rendering, then select a certain div from the page using [Simple HTML DOM PHP](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) and render that instead of the entire page, if the `header` of the page matches through `if(isset($_SERVER[]` call

Trouble is, i dont know how to do it, i cant select the current page using PHP (using `$_SERVER[]`?). I dont even know if I'm making sense.

say we start with how the external library works:

```
$html = file_get_html(''); // Get HTML of this page.. somehow
$div = $html->find('div[id=mainContent]'); // or 'div#mainContent'
```

But how do I echo the contents of that div? and will this render the page first?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain this in a cleaner way using, as suggested, `ob_get_contents`. With appropriate use of core PHP directives and inclusion, you can make it so you don't have to touch the existing PHP files *at all*!

```
<?php
    // This goes before the page, and this can be done automatically (i.e. without
    // modifying the existing PHP file) using auto prepend:
    // http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file
    ob_start();
?>

// The "old" page ...

<?php
    // This goes after the page, and again can be done automatically using
    // auto append (see above).
    // This 'if' can also check whether this page is one of those that must be
    // manipulated, or not.
    if(!isset($_SERVER['EXAMPLE_HEADER']) || ('false'==$_SERVER['EXAMPLE_HEADER']))
    {
        $html = ob_get_clean();

        // Include is only necessary in this scope -- full path may be needed, though
        include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

        // Here, $html is parsed to yield a DOM object
        // ...

        foreach($dom->find('div[id=mainContent]') as $div)
        {
            echo $div->innertext;
        }
?>
```

Comment: much easier and more productive than my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ob_start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) with [ob_get_clean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) :)

```
ob_start();

echo "Hello World";

$html = ob_get_clean();
```

now `$html` will contain `"Hello World"`. `ob_start();` needs to be at the beginning of your code, and `ob_get_clean();` in a moment where you'd like to stop collecting content.

Comment: i had looked into `ob_start` but didnt think it would work, any links to a tutorial?

Comment: see the examples in ob_get_clean. This solves your problem with getting HTML code of a page.

Comment: i see, from looking at the manual, i dont think this is quite what im looking for, as i can get the HTML. but using `ob_start` is probably heading in the right direction

Comment: Alternative way is using [get_file_content](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Like that: `$html = file_get_contents('http://google.com');` - it's quite simple, and more importantly: Allows you to read the content of external websites. You can also try to use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) - php manual is quite helpful on that, curl gives more control, but at the time is also far more difficult to use.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't got it to work, turned out I was using ob_clean() instead of ob_get_clean().

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out heres an example page:

```
<?php 
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

if(!isset($_SERVER['EXAMPLE_HEADER']) && $_SERVER['EXAMPLE_HEADER'] == 'false'){ ?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>

<?php 
}else{
$html = file_get_html('thispage.html');
foreach($html->find('div[id=mainContent]') as $div) {
echo $div->innertext;
} ?>
```

Obviously the sample html code should be your page. So the page asks if a header is sent, if not, it displays the page as usual, if it is, it will search the page for a specific div (in this case `mainContent`) and display that instead.

this will help others I guess. But using `ob_start` can help too!